# Why is domain not using d3.max(data) in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and playing around with a scatterplot.  I cannot get d3.max(data) to work correctly in setting up domain!

I have the following setting up a random dataset:

```
var data = [];
      for (i=0; i < 40; i++){
            data.push({"x": i/40, "y": i/8, "a": Math.floor(Math.random() * 3), "x2": Math.random()});
        }
```

And then the following to set my coordinates:

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).range([0 + margin, w-margin]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0 + margin, h-margin]),
            c = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 3]).range(["hsl(100,50%,50%)", "rgb(350, 50%, 50%)"]).interpolate(d3.interpolateHsl);
```

This puts all 40 points in a single, horizontal line.  If I replace d3.max(data) with '5' then it is a diagonal (albeit from the upper left to the bottom right, I'm still struggling to flip y-coordinates).  Why isn't d3.max(data) working as expected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`d3.max()` expects an array of numbers, not of objects. The elements of `data` have an internal key-value structure and there is no way for `d3.max()` to know what to take the maximum of. You can use something like [jQuery's `$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get the elements of the objects you want and then take the max, e.g.

```
var maxy = d3.max($.map(data, function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

Edit:

As pointed out in the comment below, you don't even need JQuery for this, as `.map()` is a native Array method. The code then becomes simply

```
var maxy = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

or even simpler (and for those browsers that don't implement `Array.map()`), using the optional second argument of `d3.max` that tells it how to access values within the array

```
var maxy = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for map; it's a native Array method: `d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }))`. `d3.max()` takes an optional accessor as its second argument, so you could also do `d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })`

Answer (score 4):

`d3.max` API documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_max).

> # d3.**max**(*array*[, *accessor*])
>
> Returns the maximum value in the given array using natural order. If
>   the array is empty, returns undefined. An optional accessor function
>   may be specified, which is equivalent to calling array.map(accessor)
>   before computing the maximum value. Unlike the built-in Math.max, this
>   method ignores undefined values; this is useful for computing the
>   domain of a scale while only considering the defined region of the
>   data. In addition, elements are compared using natural order rather
>   than numeric order. For example, the maximum of ["20", "3"] is "3",
>   while the maximum of [20, 3] is 20.

Applying this information to the original question we get:

```
function accessor(o){
    return o.y;
}
var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, accessor)])
        .range([0 + margin, h-margin]);
```

If you end up using many accessor functions you can just make a factory.

```
function accessor(key) {
    return function (o) {
        return o[key];
    };
}
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, accessor('x'))])
        .range([...]),
    y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, accessor('y'))])
        .range([...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue dealing with an associative array.  My data looked like the following: [{"year_decided":1982,"total":0},{"year_decided":"1983","Total":"847"},...}]

Simply passing parseInt before returning the value worked.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(query,function(d){ return parseInt(d["Total"]); }) ])
    .range([0,h]);
```