# Get the object with the max value with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects from which I can easily get a max value like this:

```
    var maxValue = d3.max(data, function (d, i) {
        return d.value
    });
```

Now, how can I get not the max value, but the object which contains this value? Is there a D3-specific way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3: use d3.max to get containing object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303888/d3-use-d3-max-to-get-containing-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for D3 here, the Javascript built-in `.sort()` is enough:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });
```

After this, `data` will be in descending order. That is, `data[0]` is the element with the highest `.value`.

Comment: First thought of doing it this way, but this is overkill and inefficient.

Comment: How is this overkill and inefficient?

Comment: I tend to use this one as a simple and efficient solution, thanks!

Comment: You are sorting the whole array just to find the max value: http://jsperf.com/walk-vs-sort

Comment: The array in this case is quite small so I think it's ok to keep codebase small.

Comment: Micro optimizations always add up.

Comment: @Metalstorm Then you should really be initialising with the largest integer so that you save the check for null: http://jsperf.com/walk-vs-sort/3

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, That code snippet doesn't work now... If anything, you could move the context check in the each function outside of the loop.

Comment: @Metalstorm Hmm, worked fine for me in Chrome -- probably the key in the object needs to be in quotes. Fixed that.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Nope still broken, check your logic, it is wrong. You are checking to see if d.value > max.value, this will never be true because max.value is the max int.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Being picky, but if there are no elements in the array then you will get a weird object with a 'huge' minus value. True you can catch an empty array outside of calling this, but its better to handle it inside and not duplicate. It's then an easy test like `if(max)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

A crude implementation:

```
(function()
{
    d3.each = function(array, fn, context)
    {
        for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            fn.call(context || this, array[i], i);
        }
    }
})();


var data = [{ 'value' : 1 }, { 'value' : 6 }, { 'value' : 100 }, { 'value' : 56 }, { 'value' : 21 }];


var max = null;
d3.each(data, function(d, i)
{
    if(!max || d.value > max.value)
    {
        max = d;
    }
});

console.log(max)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhVn4/

You also get a fancy (not really :) ) new d3 helper function (couldn't fnd it in the D3 API)

Comment: Oh dear, do I really need all this to just get the object with the biggest value? =)

Comment: You have a new helper function that can be used anywhere, and should reduce code overall (you should have this already). You have the data and you have an output. The actual code can can be 1 line if you want.