# NVD3 max value on inverted yAxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to do a simple linechart with an inverted y-axis and i'm sure my problem is easy to solve but somehow I just can't make it work.

My y-values are ranks and "1" is the best so it should be on the top of the chart.

```
chart.yDomain([10,1])
```

does the job ... but in the future we might have data outside of this domain and I try to get the maximum y-value directly from the data to replace the manually set "10".

I played around with

```
d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.rank; } )
```

and looked at [Why is domain not using d3.max(data) in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688302/why-is-domain-not-using-d3-maxdata-in-d3) but whatever I try, I can't make it work.

Maybe someone can help me out? It's the first time I'm working with nvd3 and I'm not very familiar with it.

My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Marei/w0385jj3/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `d3.merge` with a `.map`

```
d3.max(d3.merge(data.map(function(d){return d.values})), function(d) {return d.rank});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0385jj3/3/).

Comment: @Marei, well that's embarrassing, see new answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem is, that it takes the max only from the first key in the data, not the second key. But you did point me in the right direction and I have figured it out!  var maxY = d3.max(d3.entries(data), function(d) {
  return d3.max(d3.entries(d.value), function(e) {
      return d3.max(e.value, function(f) { return f.rank; });
  });
});